# Which parts of Magento query the sales_flat_quote_address table

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log

I am trying to debug an error that is killing my site (restarting apache on a regular basis).
The error in the error_log is an Exit Signal Segmentation Fault.

I have had my hosts try to run a backtrace on the coredump for when this error occurs, and all they can give me is that it has something to do with a query on the sales_flat_quote_address table happening multiple times (looping) and causing the crash. This apparently comes from the index.php file in the site root. Erm, yeah, everything goes through that file in Magento :-(

Bear in mind, there are no other errors logged when this happens, so it's not like the error_log is filling up with errors due to something breaking in Magento.

This is making it extremely hard to debug the problem.

I figured I need to understand which parts of Magento create queries accessing sales_flat_quote_address, and maybe I can go from there?

I would guess it will be something to do with the display of the shopping basket, but at what point in the application would Magento be triggered into performing multiple queries for the exact same information - and why?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A segementation fault is an internal error in php (or, less likely, apache). Oftentimes, the segmentation fault is caused by one of the newer and lesser-tested php modules such as imagemagick or subversion.

Try disabling all non-essential modules (in php.ini), and then re-enabling them one-by-one until the error occurs. You may also want to update php and apache.

If that doesn't help, you should report a php bug.